# @media query works fine in browser resize but not on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

This media query works fine when resizing in a browser but it doesn't work on mobile devices

> @media handheld,screen and(max-width:870px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiny little slip up in your code.  You need a space between "and" and "(".

Not sure why this happens, but it seems to bother mobile platforms while desktop platforms work fine without the space.

Hope it works out for you.